# Count Comma Separated Values from single column with specific conditions

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `live_product` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_details` text NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `tag1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tag2` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

INSERT INTO `live_product` (`id`, `product_details`, `price`,   `tag1`, `tag2`) VALUES
(1, 'Product 1', '302.54', 'man,boy,girl', '22'),
(2, 'Product 2', '457.00', 'man,girl', '22'),
(3, 'Product 3', '157.00', 'girl', '24'),
(4, 'Product 4', '1157.00','man,boy,girl', '22'),
(5, 'Product 5', '957.00', 'man,boy,girl', '22'),
(6, 'Product 6', '757.00', 'boy,girl', '22'),
(7, 'Product 7', '157.00', 'boy', '24');
```

Required 2 results from 2 mysql queries for advanced search

> ```
> +------+-------------+
> | Tag1 | Total_Count |
> +------+-------------+
> | girl |           6 |
> | man  |           4 |
> +------+-------------+
> ```

2. This Result need

> ```
> +----+-----------------+---------+--------------+------+
> | id | product_details | price   | tag1         | tag2 |
> +----+-----------------+---------+--------------+------+
> |  1 | Product 1       |  302.54 | man,boy,girl | 22   |
> |  2 | Product 2       |  457.00 | man,girl     | 22   |
> |  3 | Product 3       |  157.00 | girl         | 24   |
> |  4 | Product 4       | 1157.00 | man,boy,girl | 22   |
> |  5 | Product 5       |  957.00 | man,boy,girl | 22   |
> |  6 | Product 6       |  757.00 | boy, girl    | 22   |
> +----+-----------------+---------+--------------+------+
> ```

```
SELECT t.tag1 as Tag1, count(*) AS Total_Count FROM
    (SELECT
      live_product.id,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(live_product.tag1, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) tag1
    FROM
      (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2
       UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) numbers INNER JOIN live_product
      ON CHAR_LENGTH(live_product.tag1)
         -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(live_product.tag1, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
    ORDER BY
      id, n) t
    GROUP BY t.tag1
    ORDER BY Total_Count DESC, t.tag1 ASC;
```

Above query only providing  comma separated count but it giving wrong result when i add more where conditions like price between.

Comment: Do you have any reason against having the tags in a separate table? That would make this query very simple, and you could still retrieve the tags for products comma separated with GROUP_CONCAT().

Comment: Like tag1 many other kinds of tags are available in this table, where i need to filter equals, between and like etc to get my result

Answer (score 0):

Try it if it works for you-

```
SELECT b.sub AS Tag1, COUNT(a.id) AS Total_Count FROM 
live_product a 
JOIN 
(
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag1,',',1) sub FROM live_product UNION 
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag1,',',2),',',-1) sub FROM live_product UNION 
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag1,',',-1) FROM live_product sub
) b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.sub,a.tag1) 
GROUP BY b.sub;
```

Comment: having problem,  when i search find_in_set('girl,boy', tag1) using above query

Comment: if you create a #sqlfiddle then i can help you, as not able to understand what error you are getting.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec58f/2

in where condition i need to filter 'boy,girl' counting alone

Comment: you may accept it by green tick if it works for you... :)